# Model validation using Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, validation, data-annotations, system.componentmodel

I have a Entity Framework model class that has a view to create an instance of that model class.  I wanted to validate dates on that class so that users add dates that meet certain criteria. I have a metadata class that uses attributes from the `System.ComponentModel` and `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespaces.

Is there any attribute from there that I can use to perform the validation or is there some other way I can do this?

Comment: Hard to say without more details / examples. I suppose you mean they are constraints on your possible dates coming from different properties of your model ? If so (and even if not), I would take a look at FluentValidation http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

Comment: All it is, is that I have two dates - a start and an end date = the start date has to be before the end date - that's all - I just don't know where to put that code.

Comment: So you'll need a CustomValidationAttribute, as existing attributes don't know their "object" (each property has no idea of other properties of the instance). Or use FluentValidation. Or use Fluentvalidation. Or use FluentValidation. ;)

Comment: :-).  I think I might use FluentValidation then :-)

Comment: @dskh hmm.  Good point - not sure how I can do that though

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I can't get FluentValidation to work.  It won't recognise the Validator attribute.  I'm using http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc

Comment: You downloaded FluentValidation, read doc,  added references in your project (FluentValidation.dll), used the right "using"s (`using FluentValidation;`) in so little time ? (kidding, but there must be a ref / using missing somehwere).

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I'm using "using FluentValidation.Mvc;"

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I've got it all sorted - please post a quick answer so I can mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a CustomValidationAttribute, as existing attributes don't know their "object" (each property has no idea of other properties of the instance).

But my choice would go to FluentValidation, which has a nice fluent interface and give you the choice to interact between the properties of the object to validate.

http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CustomValidationAttribute` to do whatever additional validation you want.  You'll have to work a bit harder if you need client-side validation to go with it though!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute.aspx